# Catching exception failure

Tags: java, exception

I try to catch a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, but it does not work, and i cannot  figure out why?  Could you give me some idea or hint, why does this happen??

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println(getSelectedUser());
                try{
                    System.out.println("deleting id:" +Integer.parseInt((String)table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0)));
                    table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0)));
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmBugSurveilance, "Please select an user!");
                }
                  catch (Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmBugSurveilance, "Please select an user!");
            }

                getUsers();
            }
        });
```

I need to handle the case where the user does not click some row from the Jtable...

How the program crashes:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.Vector.elementData(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
    at view.AdminGui.getSelectedUser(AdminGui.java:237)
    at view.AdminGui$3.actionPerformed(AdminGui.java:149)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Why on earth would you want to catch that exception? Why not just handle it instead? Just fix whatever method is throwing it to only accept valid input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your `try` block is in the wrong place.  Look at the stack trace here:

```
    at view.AdminGui.getSelectedUser(AdminGui.java:237)
```

and notice that you're calling that method *before* your `try` block:

```
System.out.println(getSelectedUser());
```

Rewrite to this:

```
try{
    System.out.println(getSelectedUser());
    System.out.println("deleting id:" +Integer.parseInt((String)table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0)));
    // ...
```

Comment: If you use a symbolic debugger like Eclipse's or other IDEs', this is especially easy to diagnose because they'll take you right to the line of your code that's throwing the error.